# Docker official registry (Docker Hub) URL

Tags: docker, dockerhub

Docker Hub official website has been moved to https://registry.hub.docker.com from https://hub.docker.com/.

If I try to `docker pull` images from URL like: `docker pull registry.hub.docker.com/busybox`  it shows:

```
registry.hub.docker.com/busybox: this image was pulled from a legacy registry.  
Important: This registry version will not be supported in future versions of docker.
```

But if I use `docker pull registry.hub.docker.com/busybox`.

It cannot pull the image.

Same situation when using `curl -k https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/busybox/tags`

UPDATE AS of 2022 / Q3:
use docker.io
example docker.io/nginx

Answer (score 135):

For those trying to create a Google Cloud instance using the "Deploy a container image to this VM instance." option then the correct url format would be

> `docker.io/<dockerimagename>:version`

The suggestion of `registry.hub.docker.com/library/<dockerimagename>` did not work for me.

I finally found the solution [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/create-configure-instance) (in my case, i was trying to run docker.io/tensorflow/serving:latest)

Comment: I agree that `docker.io` seems like the safest url to use (least likely to change/break in the future). The [registry docs](https://docs.docker.com/registry/introduction/) say "docker pull ubuntu ... is simply a shortcut for the longer docker pull docker.io/library/ubuntu command".

Comment: docker.io works out of the box

Answer (score 122):

The registry path for official images (without a slash in the name) is `library/<image>`. Try this instead:

```
docker pull registry.hub.docker.com/library/busybox
```

Comment: any idea with personal images ? I mean for <user>/<image> container, any help with full url ?

Comment: @JoséIbañez, did you try `docker pull registry.hub.docker.com/<user>/<image>` ?

Comment: The URL to use is `docker pull index.docker.io/library/busybox`

Comment: I think it's safest to use `docker.io` instead of `registry.hub.docker.com`, `index.docker.io`, etc because it is the most generic alias. The [registry docs](https://docs.docker.com/registry/introduction/) say "`docker pull ubuntu` ... is simply a shortcut for the longer `docker pull docker.io/library/ubuntu` command"

Comment: @wisbucky omg GEEZ OH MAN thank you. My goodness why was this so ridiculous to find.

Answer (score 39):

This answer is not valid for "Docker Desktop" where the `Registry` key doesn't appear. This might be true for recent versions of the "former" Docker Engine - please drop me a line if that's the case.

---

#### Docker Engine

You're able to get the current registry-url using `docker info`:

```
...
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
...
```

---

That's also the url you may use to run your self hosted-registry:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --name registry -e REGISTRY_PROXY_REMOTEURL=https://index.docker.io registry:2
```

---

*ix friends, grep & use it right away:

```
$ echo $(docker info | grep -oP "(?<=Registry: ).*")
https://index.docker.io/v1/
```

Comment: Given that the registry URL could change in the future, using `docker info` would seem to be the safest method.

Comment: It's wright @Raedwald. Moreover, `docker info` works on Windows, `grep` doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for your hint @RobertoC.Rodriguez-Hidalgo, i drafted a Windows version of the command. Unfortunately i'm not able to test it (no Windows available).

Comment: The URL is actually an [index server address](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/v20.10.18/cli/command/system/info.go#L255). A while ago there seemed to be a [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28394930) between an index server and a registry. These days I'm not sure. Anyway, the response I get is 404. Although with /v2/ it works. Which sounds suspicious. I'd use the one that `docker` uses. And that's `registry-1.docker.io`. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73893304/52499).

Comment: Interesting - i don't have issues using index.docker.io.. I have an eye on it..

Comment: There are some compatibility issues at play here. A lot of source code depends on the way things work right now. But they're planning to change something. More on it [here](https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/3793#issuecomment-1269051403). About 404 I meant the exact URL in your answer. You can use the registry API with `index.docker.io`, but `/v1/` results in 404. And the source code uses `registry-1.docker.io` (e.g. `docker pull`). So I find the latter more preferable.

Comment: Good finding - thank you @x-yuri - i hope they will update the url the registry field of the `docker info` output points at.. i keep an eye on it. But the `index.docker.io` output here should have been taken as example output. IMaybe i should make tha answer more clear on that.

Answer (score 15):

I came across this post in search for the dockerhub repo URL when creating a dockerhub kubernetes secret.. figured id share the URL is used with success, hope that's ok.

**Live**
Current: https://index.docker.io/v2/

**Dead**
Orginal: https://index.docker.io/v1/

Comment: Second this solution, very useful when using w/ kubernetes secret. The official doc points out that `https://index.docker.io/v1/` is indeed the dockerhub url to use. See: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/#create-a-secret-by-providing-credentials-on-the-command-line

Comment: The `v2` should not be specified in a `pull`, so just e.g. `docker | podman | crictl pull index.docker.io/hello-world`

Comment: How come `https://index.docker.io/v1/` is dead, but I still see it when typing `docker info`? docker is so clunky with its documentation..

Answer (score 9):

**tl;dr** `registry-1.docker.io` for API requests, `docker.io` for `docker pull`

The situation is tricky and there are [plans](https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/3793#issuecomment-1269051403) to address it in the future. I know 3 relevant domains here:

- `index.docker.io` ([legacy](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/v20.10.18/vendor/github.com/docker/distribution/reference/normalize.go#L13)?)
- `docker.io`
- `registry-1.docker.io`

You can use any of those with `docker pull`:

- `docker pull index.docker.io/library/alpine`
- `docker pull docker.io/library/alpine`
- `docker pull registry-1.docker.io/library/alpine`

`index.docker.io` is treated the same as `docker.io` (the former [gets replaced](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/v20.10.18/vendor/github.com/docker/distribution/reference/normalize.go#L98) with the latter).

In all three cases `registry-1.docker.io` is used to connect to the registry. In the first 2 cases that is the [default](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/v20.10.18/registry/service_v2.go#L33-L39) registry [URL](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/v22.06.0-beta.0/registry/config.go#L25-L55). In the third case `registry-1.docker.io` is taken [as is](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/v20.10.18/registry/service_v2.go#L51-L62).

Then, to use the [registry API](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/) you can use `index.docker.io` and `registry-1.docker.io` (`docker.io` doesn't work). E.g.:

```
$ curl -sSv https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/
```

Also, apparently the domains are going to [change](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/v22.06.0-beta.0/registry/config.go#L25-L55) in the future.

`docker.io` is most often used in the context of `docker pull`. `index.docker.io` seems to go back to the times where Docker Hub [was called](https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/3793#issuecomment-1269051403) Docker Index and to a concept of an index server (searching for images). Actually, that's probably the main purpose of this domain:

https://index.docker.io/v1/search/

Searching isn't a part of the docker registry spec. Or its generalization/successor (?) called [OCI Distribution Spec](https://github.com/opencontainers/distribution-spec/blob/v1.0.1/spec.md).

Answer (score 1):

It's just `docker pull busybox`, are you using an up to date version of the `docker` client. I think they stopped supporting clients lower than 1.5.

Incidentally that curl works for me:

```
$ curl -k https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/busybox/tags
[{"layer": "fc0db02f", "name": "latest"}, {"layer": "fc0db02f", "name": "1"}, {"layer": "a6dbc8d6", "name": "1-ubuntu"}, {"layer": "a6dbc8d6", "name": "1.21-ubuntu"}, {"layer": "a6dbc8d6", "name": "1.21.0-ubuntu"}, {"layer": "d7057cb0", "name": "1.23"}, {"layer": "d7057cb0", "name": "1.23.2"}, {"layer": "fc0db02f", "name": "1.24"}, {"layer": "3d5bcd78", "name": "1.24.0"}, {"layer": "fc0db02f", "name": "1.24.1"}, {"layer": "1c677c87", "name": "buildroot-2013.08.1"}, {"layer": "0f864637", "name": "buildroot-2014.02"}, {"layer": "a6dbc8d6", "name": "ubuntu"}, {"layer": "ff8f955d", "name": "ubuntu-12.04"}, {"layer": "633fcd11", "name": "ubuntu-14.04"}]
```

Interesting enough if you sniff the headers you get a HTTP 405 (Method not allowed). I think this might be to do with the fact that Docker have deprecated their [Registry API](http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/hub_registry_spec/).

Comment: I know I can use ```docker pull busybox```.  But in my case I have using curl to get some information. But I am afraid it will remove in the future. So, I have to check what URL is the latest.

Comment: These days the `curl` command responds with 410 GONE.

Answer (score 1):

For those wanting to explicitly declare they are pulling from dockerhub when using fabric8 maven plugin, add a new property: `<docker.pull.registry>registry.hub.docker.com/library</docker.pull.registry>`

I arrived on this page trying to solve problem of pulling from my AWS ECR registry when building Docker images using fabric8.

Comment: fabric8 discontinued.

Answer (score 0):

Use this tool:

https://github.com/amjad489/docker-pull-push

```
docker-pull-push -s docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.13 -t AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/elasticsearch:7.13.3

Usage:
  docker-pull-push [flags]

Flags:
  -p, --awsProfile string     AWS profile (default "default")
  -l, --awsRegion string      AWS Region (default "us-east-1")
  -h, --help                  help for docker-pull-push
  -r, --registryType string   ECR (default "docker")
  -s, --sourceImage string    docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.13
  -t, --targetImage string    AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/elasticsearch:7.13.3
```